# Add dynamic handler with dojo

Tags: javascript, dom, dojo

I'm using dojo v1.6 and trying to dynamically add an event handler to the menu `onShow` event. There's no exceptions thrown yet the alert window is not displayed. What do I do wrong?

```
dojo.require("dojox.NodeList.delegate");
dojo.query("body").delegate(dojo.byId("dijit_Menu_1"), "onshow", function(){
    alert("Show!!!");
});
```

Comment: since it is a dijit widget : did you try "onShow" (camel case) ?

Comment: yes I tried, it didn't help..

Comment: and you tried dijit.byId("dijit_Menu_1"), "onShow" (not dojo.byId) ? Using 1.9 here allover.

Comment: I've just tried it (of course should've used it before since I want to get dijjit object back) but still no effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dijit.byId` of the menu with `onOpen` seems to be working fine for me . 
Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/prak5190/bEurr/3/

Also make sure that you are taking the id of the right dijit (was making that mistake - was using `dijit_Menu_1` instead of `dijit_Menu_0` ). Better to either keep a reference of the widget or give it an id .

Comment: Worked for me to! Which is strange given that both onShow and onOpen are documented methods and only one of them works as it supposed to